# Работает только первая ссылка  (скрыть-открыть div) в PHP через jQuery

Tags: jquery, php

Доброго времени суток, у меня такая проблема: делаю выборку из базы, ссылок и контейнер с формой, изначально форма скрыта, а при нажатии на ссылку она должна раскрываться, так вот работает только первая ссылка, а остальные нет, скрывает и закрывает блок через jQuery.

```
echo "<div class='doctor_z_4'>" . "<a href='#' id='fa'>" . $talon_time['date_talon'] . "\n" . substr($talon_time['time_talon_tima'], 0, 5) . " - " . "</a>" . "<p>" . $talon_time['talon_status_text'] . "</p>" . "</div>";
echo "<div class='line'></div>";
echo "<div id='block' style='display:none;'>";
echo "<div class='zap_tal_1'>Здравствуйте! " . "Ваш талон № " . "<b class='zap_tal_2'>" . $talon_time['id_talon'] . "</b>" . "</div>";
echo "<div class='zap_tal'> Ваш врач: " . "<b class='zap_tal_2'>" . $mass_doctor['last'] . "\n" . $mass_doctor['first'] . "\n" . $mass_doctor['middle'] . "</b>" . "</div>";
echo "<div class='zap_tal'> День приёма: " . "<b class='zap_tal_2'>" . $talon_time['date_talon'] . "</b>" . "</div>";
echo "<div class='zap_tal'> Время приёма: " . "<b class='zap_tal_2'>" . substr($talon_time['time_talon_tima'], 0, 5) . "</b>" . "</div>";
echo "<div class='line'></div>";
echo "<form method='post' action='lesson20.php'>";
echo "  <div class='formochka'>";
echo "  <div class='formochka_text'>";
echo "  <p>Имя ребёнка:</p>";
echo "  </div>";
echo "  <div class='formochka_input'>";
echo "  <input class='name_reb' type='text' name='name_reb'/>";
echo "  </div>";
echo "  </div>";
echo "  <div class='formochka'>";
echo "  <div class='formochka_text'>";
echo "  <p>Фамилия ребёнка:</p>";
echo "  </div>";
echo "  <div class='formochka_input'>";
echo "  <input class='name_reb' type='text' name='fam_reb'/>";
echo "  </div>";
echo "  </div>";
echo "  <div class='formochka'>";
echo "  <div class='formochka_text'>";
echo "  <p>Отчество ребёнка:</p>";
echo "  </div>";
echo "  <div class='formochka_input'>";
echo "  <input class='name_reb' type='text' name='middle'/>";
echo "  </div>";
echo "  </div>";
echo "  <div class='formochka'>";
echo "  <div class='formochka_text'>";
echo "  <p>Домашний адрес:</p>";
echo "  </div>";
echo "  <div class='formochka_input'>";
echo "  <input class='name_reb' type='text' name='adres_dom'/>";
echo "  </div>";
echo "  </div>";
echo "  <div class='formochka'>";
echo "  <div class='formochka_text'>";
echo "  <p>Домашний телефон:</p>";
echo "  </div>";
echo "  <div class='formochka_input'>";
echo "  <input class='name_reb' type='text' name='tel_dom'/>";
echo "  </div>";
echo "  </div>";
echo "  <div class='formochka'>";
echo "  <div class='formochka_text'>";
echo "  <p>Сотовый телефон:</p>";
echo "  </div>";
echo "  <div class='formochka_input'>";
echo "  <input class='name_reb' type='text' name='te_sot'/>";
echo "  </div>";
echo "  </div>";
echo "  <div class='formochka'>";
echo "  <div class='formochka_text'>";
echo "  <p>Укажите пол:</p>";
echo "  </div>";
echo "  <div class='formochka_input'>";
echo "  <input type='radio' name='sex' value='M' /> Мужской \n";
echo "  <input type='radio' name='sex' value='G' /> Женский ";
echo "  </div>";
echo "  </div>";
echo "  <div class='formochka'>";
echo "  <div class='formochka_text'>";
echo "  <p>Ваш E-mail:</p>";
echo "  </div>";
echo "  <div class='formochka_input'>";
echo "  <input class='name_reb' type='email' name='mail'/>";
echo "  </div>";
echo "  </div>";
echo "  <input type='submit' value=' Записаться ' />";
echo "</form>";
echo "</div>";
```

А вот и jQuery

```
<script>
    $('#fa').toggle(function () {
        $('#block').show('bounce', 500);
    }, function () {
        $('#block').hide('bounce', 500);
    });
</script>
```

Comment: @dimka1judo, вы шутите? Чтобы отформатировать код, выделите его мышью и нажмите на кнопку 101010 редактора.

Answer (score 1):

Судя по вашему коду, у вас все ссылки имеют одинаковый id, а такого быть не должно. Измените на класс.

**Дополнение**

```
$('.fa').toggle(function () {
    $(this).parent().siblings('.block').show('bounce', 500);
}, function () {
    $(this).parent().siblings('.block').hide('bounce', 500);
});
```

Comment: Поменял всё на классы, но теперь все правда ссылки работают, но при нажатии на любую из них сразу все блоки появляются, а как сделать чтоы появлялся только 1, активный чтоли

Comment: Дополнил в ответе

Answer (score 0):

По теме вопроса, так, на вскидку, ибо код html *было* разобрать сложновато, в javascript у тебя производится селект по id элемента, который должен быть уникальным на странице, поэтому у тебя событие срабатывает только на одном элементе

P.S. Чувак, нафига на каждую строку html писать echo? Всеравно, в твоем стиле, весь html на странице будет без отступов и переносов. Если сильно хочется печатать html из php скрипта, то никто тебе не запрещает использовать только один echo вначале, а потом целый блок отформатированного кода со вставленными переменными, так и форматирование исходного html кода на странице появится и переменные передашь. Пр:

```
echo '<div class="header">
     <ul id="nav">
         <li>
            <a href="' . {$data['main_url']} . '">' . {$data['main_label']} . '</a>
         </li>
         <li>
            <a href="' . {$data['about_url']} . '">' . {$data['about_label']} . '</a>
         </li>
         <li>
            <a href="' . {$data['other_url']} . '">' . {$data['other_label']} . '</a>
         </li>
     </ul>
</div>';
```